# iOS show/hide onscreen keyboard with external keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, external-accessory

I have a company app (not on AppStore) that I'm attempting to use with a wired barcode scanner, but also need the onscreen keyboard for manual entry.  The scanner itself does not have any "show/hide keyboard" button.  I am connecting the scanner with an Apple Lighting to USB3 Adapter, which works great - it connects as an external keyboard.

There are flows in the app that require a user to enter text when a barcode is not available to scan, e.g. login flow.  How can I programmatically show the onscreen keyboard for these flows on an iPhone or iPod?

I have used bluetooth scanners that have a button to show/hide the onscreen keyboard.  Is it possible to simulate this functionality in code?

The last resort may be to create my own onscreen "keyboard" that I can show and hide at will.

Comment: You can add an UITextField and focus it with calling becomeFirstResponder. If you want to hide it you can set alpha as 0.0. Keyboard will shown when you focus it.

Comment: @ibrahimyilmaz the on-screen keyboard is not shown if an external keyboard is connected, which is the issue I'm having.